# Conditional Validation in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller

In my application I want to implement the conditional validation and I am new to MVC.
My code looks like this.

```
public class ConditionalValidation : IValidatableObject
    {
        public bool ValidateName { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (ValidateName)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
                {
                    yield return new ValidationResult("*");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I am accessing view of this no validation is working either I checked the checkbox or not and the page is submitting without checking the client side validation.
I checked the `ModelState.IsVlaid` at the controller but is also `true` so please suggest where I am doing working.

Thanks

Comment: Well i checked it is working on the server side but as we use simple validations on the model, the mvc framework automatically generate client side validations but in this case not. so there is any way to generate it from the model instead of writing the self javascript validation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the required data annotation attributes.

Reference here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx

Try this...

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class ConditionalValidation : IValidatableObject
    {
        public bool ValidateName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage=@"Name is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (ValidateName)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
                {
                    yield return new ValidationResult("*");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**:
Also, make sure your web.config has the following in the <appSettings>:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

and that you have included the following on your page:

jquery.validate.min.js

jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

Here are some tutorials I found:

[Unobtrusive Client Validation in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)

[Exercise 4: Using Unobtrusive jQuery at Client Side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg618489)

Comment: Its good and but now working on the client side. is there other stuff i have to add for the client side ?